# Three Logins using One Login Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authorization

Been stuck on this for a few hours so some help would be greatly appreciated!

I want to have three Roles: A "SuperUser" who can do everything on my System, an "Administrator" who can do certain things and just a general "User".

The "User" will not have access to the system until they are authorized by an "Administrator" or "SuperUser".

I've set up my Database and all the roles are there along the UserProfile, webpages_Membership, Roles etc.

I want to have a single login page. All three roles will be able to login there but I'm having problems with someone who can just register and access the site straight away. Is there any way to limit who can login until I can assign them the "User" role?

Here is the login of my Accounts Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

I've been toying with [Authorize] and User.IsInRole("User") but nothing is helping.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the concepts of authentication and authorization. Any active user can authenticate and there's no issue with that. If someone is newly registered and signs in before they are granted "access" to anything, that's fine. They should simply be presented with some sort of message saying they don't have access yet or redirected to some sandbox where there's essentially nothing they can do.

Authorization is a totally separate layer. You authorize certain areas of the site for different roles and only users who are in that role can then access those areas. You do this using the `Authorize` attribute, along with a list of roles. For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Superuser,Admin")]
public ActionResult SensitiveAction()
```

Now only users in those roles may access this action. Anyone else is denied. Further, you can hide the links and such to these areas based on the role:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Superuser") || User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <a href="/admins/only">Admins Only!</a>
}
```

Users not in those roles, then, will never see this.

Comment: How can I then send a User who is authenticated but not authorized to a separate page via the Account Controller?

Comment: This happens automatically via the `Authorize` attribute, but if you want to handle it manually or do something very specific, you can simply check if the user is in a specific role or not (`User.IsInRole("Role")`) and then redirect accordingly in the conditional. You can also create your own action filters (usually deriving from `AuthorizeAttribute`) to do more custom things and then use those instead of `Authorize`. It's entirely up to you. All the tools are there, you just need to utilize them.

Comment: I've honestly tried the User.IsInRole("Role") and none of them and I got nothing. I think I'll try creating the my own action filters next. Thanks for the help and I'll get back to you if I can figure it out or not.